# firebase crashlytic on cached_network_image

Tags: flutter, firebase-crash-reporting

In firebase crashlytic, i constantly receive two types of crash exception from this package [cache_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image).
Below are the exception

```
1: ImageLoader.loadImageAsync.<fn> io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError - Exception: Invalid image data. Error thrown resolving an image codec.
2: ImageLoader.loadBufferAsync.<fn> io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError - Exception: Invalid image data. Error thrown resolving an image codec.

Stacktrace

(1.)
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError 
Exception: Invalid image data. Error thrown resolving an image codec..instantiateImageCodecWithSize (dart:ui)
ImageLoader.loadImageAsync.<fn> (_image_loader.dart:68)
ImageLoader._load (_image_loader.dart:129)
new MultiImageStreamCompleter.<fn> (multi_image_stream_completer.dart:26)
(2.)
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError 
Exception: Invalid image data. Error thrown resolving an image codec..instantiateImageCodecWithSize (dart:ui)
ImageLoader.loadBufferAsync.<fn> (_image_loader.dart:68)
ImageLoader._load (_image_loader.dart:129)
new MultiImageStreamCompleter.<fn> (multi_image_stream_completer.dart:26)

Keys:
flutter_error_exception Exception: Invalid image data
flutter_error_reason    thrown resolving an image codec
```

Below is the code I use

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    width: ScreenHelper().getScreenWidth(0.35),
    height: ScreenHelper().getScreenHeight(0.18),
    progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) =>
          SkeletonContainer.square(
              width: ScreenHelper().getScreenWidth(0.35),
              height: ScreenHelper().getScreenHeight(0.18),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
    imageUrl: imgUrl,
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset(
                  AppAsset.appLogo,
                  gaplessPlayback: true,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
),
```

My question is, does this exception is common for this package? the crash event counts keep stacking and exceed thousands. But `errorWidget` is used to handle what to render if image failed loading right? Why the exception still constantly trigger. Or I actually didn't handle this package correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue myself these last few months. The issue is with the CachedNetworkImage library. Try to handle it by updating the crashlytics error recorder to ignore it

For more information see https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/336#issuecomment-1693519544

```dart
FlutterError.onError = (flutterErrorDetails) async {
if (flutterErrorDetails.library == "image resource service" &&
    flutterErrorDetails.exception
        .toString()
        .startsWith("HttpException: Invalid statusCode: 404, uri")) {
  return;
}
await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
    .recordFlutterFatalError(flutterErrorDetails);
return;
};
```